# Docker group assignment doesn't affect the user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, docker, user-groups

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. On the manual page on how to use docker without `sudo` it is written that user should add himself to the `docker` group and perform logout/login for changes to take affect. I created a group, added my user to that group, performed `su $USER` and then `groups` command started to show the group `docker` in the list of groups that my user is part of. But when I close the terminal and open it again I do not see that my user is part of `docker` group. I still need to perform `su $USER` command to be able to join to the `docker` group again.

Why this happens?

PS. However `cat /etc/group` **always** shows that my user is part of the `docker` group.

**Update**
I've also tried to logout/login from ubuntu - the result is same

**Update final**
Restarted the system once again and changes applied(now new terminal does see current user in `docker` group). Perhaps some problems with ubuntu 18.04 log out process

Comment: I have this exact same issue on Mint 2020. No KWallet installed so it isn't the bug listed in the answer of @BMitch (though I don't deny it's a bug)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overall X Windows system (Gnome, KDE, etc) is forking off the terminal with the credentials it already has without triggering a new login. You need to logout completely and then log back in again for the group membership change to take effect.

In the short term, instead of an `su $USER` command, you can run `newgrp docker` in any shell to get access to that new group.

Comment: is there any way not to do this on new terminal or after system restart or after logout/login?

Comment: @maks It doesn't sound like you've tried a logout/login from the question.

Comment: I've updated the question. Actually at first i wrote about logout/login process, but then encountered that it happens even in a new terminal window, so updated the question

Comment: @maks If you're seeing the issue after a full logout/login, then that's a bug/defect. Others have reported this which may apply to you: https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+bug/1781418

Comment: tried to add `newgrp docker` to bashrc file, but after that new terminal can't be opened. Is there some prrocess that could automate `newgrp docker`?

Comment: I've never tried to put newgrp inside of a bashrc, it might call the shell with a login command itself, throwing you in a loop. Or it might launch a shell right there, stopping the rest of the bashrc.